# PHP: Delay parsing of page source (via file_get_html()) by 1 second

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP to try and scrape a page that seems to dynamically load content just milliseconds after the parent page finishes loading.

I am using curl to parse the page, and simpleHtmlDom to snatch things from the parsed html.

My efforts to traverse the DOM and explode() things out of the html return nothing.  My only ideas were that it was loading the content *after* the parent page was loaded.

Here is my code.

```
<? 
 $url = 'http://www.facebook.com/OneAndroidAppaDay';
 $scrapeUrl = 'http://www.facebook.com/OneAndroidAppaDay';

  include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
  require_once("bitly.php");

  $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$scrapeUrl);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  $html = curl_exec($ch);
  if (!$html) {
   echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
   echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
   exit;
  }

  $appBitlyUrl = $html->find('div[class=UIStoryAttachment_Title]',0)->find('a',0)->href; // fail :(
  echo 'Bitly Url:  ' . $appBitlyUrl;
?>
```

It's bombing out at line 24 (denoted with the inline comment) with this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/xxxxxxxx/public_html/xxx.xx/xxxx.php on line 24

Is there a way to make it wait a second or two before it snatches the page's html?  Or maybe someone has some better insight?

Thanks

Mark

Comment: Any sort of delay has nothing to do with the error message you currently have.

Comment: Btw, scraping the contents of any application at facebook is out of their TOS and illegal, downvoted.

Comment: Upvoted back to zero. This is not a legal counselling site. And besides Facebook having no copyright authority over user contributed content, scraping for personal use is seldomly illegal. (Yes, I'm aware that I'm making assumptions too.)

Answer (score 1):

to do a simple delay

```
sleep(2); // 2 second delay before continuing
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really re-read the error message. It doesn't stem from a timing issue.

You get a $html string from curl. But you cannot invoke phphtmldom functions ->find on that right away. You'll have to parse it before traversing. Also it's unclear why you are using curl in the first place. Either use just `$dom = str_get_html($html)` or try:

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://www.facebook.com/OneAndroidAppaDay');

$bituurl = $dom->find('div[class=UIStoryAttachment_Title]',0)->...
```

Comment: I had been using file_get_html() in the past, which still throws the same error.  I assumed that it was just trying to traverse things that weren't there yet.

Comment: @marky-b: That must be a bug with simplehtmldom then. `print_r` whatever you get back to see if it is an object. Else try the str_ variant for parsing. Or better yet migrate to phpQuery or QueryPath, two good alternatives.